# Linker error when trying to add constant to iterator

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    static const int X = 3;
    static char bar(const string &str) {
        // return str[X]; // this works
        return *(str.begin() + X); // this fails
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << foo::bar("abcdefg") << endl;
}
```

When compiling this, I get a linker error saying "undefined symbol foo::X". If the previous line is uncommented instead, then it compiles. What makes it different between these two?

Comment: what is your compiler? the code works for me.

Comment: Is the inline definition allowed in C++0x? Try compiling with `-std=c++0x`...

Comment: Kerrek SB: actually I am compiling with -std=c++0x, because I am using other features with the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you try changing the type of `X` to `std::string::iterator::distance_type`? It shouldn't make a difference but then again, the code you've posted works fine for me.

Comment: It works for me with `gcc -O2` and doesn't with `gcc -O0`, so it depends on whether the reference to X is optimizet out by the compiler.

Comment: n.m.: Thanks, that seems quite possibly what's going on here. The compiler seems to optimize str[X] even without -O2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `foo::X` in addition to declaring it. Do it outside of `foo`.

```
const int foo::X;
```

Comment: AFAIK static integral constant members can be initialized within the class declaration itself. And the code posted code works just fine on VS2008 and ideone (gcc 4.3.4)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was wondering why `str[X]` works even without the outside definition.

Comment: @hrzap: your code works with GCC 4.5.2 and 4.6.0, clang 2.9 and ICC 11.1

Comment: *If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression. In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.*